# How can I validate the email writing on UWP?

Tags: windows-10

Currently I'm working on an app that requires as mandatory a valid email address for the confirmation and validation of the account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way..

```
public void Register(){
    string email = "youremail";

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email) || !Regex.IsMatch(email, @"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"))
    {
        DialogHelper.ShowToast(string.Empty, "The email is invalid");
        return;
    }

    //Continue with your register logic...
}
```

DialogService.cs

```
public class DialogService
{
    public static void ShowToast(string message, string title)
    {
        var notificationXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText02);
        var toastElement = notificationXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
        toastElement[0].AppendChild(notificationXml.CreateTextNode(title));
        toastElement[1].AppendChild(notificationXml.CreateTextNode(message));
        var toastNotification = new ToastNotification(notificationXml);
        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toastNotification);
    }
}
```