# Validate email and show error as a toast - uwp

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, toast

I want to validate email address and need to show error message as a toast. I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314285/how-can-i-validate-the-email-writing-on-uwp). 
It shows toast well. But those toast messages are coming as notification on notification area of device. Actually for validation purposes we really don't need those notification, only need to show toast on current page. How to do it?

Comment: That doesn't make a good UX. Why not validate by disabling any submit button and indicating the error in a label?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if only want it on the page you have to use a xaml control and don't use the notification check the Windows Community toolkit; it has a in app notification control. maybe that one is useful for you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/controls/inappnotification

Comment: This is the correct answer. Using notifications for this is not the correct usage of notifications. OP is likely coming from an Android background, where a "toast" is a brief in-context text popup, whereas in Windows, a "toast" is a notification.